# Does Amazon S3 check integrity when copying from a bucket to another?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, checksum

I have a question about **Amazon S3** Copy, I am using **boto3** in **Python**.
When **AWS** copies between buckets, does it perform a checksum or verify the integrity of the copied objects?
Should we trust that if it does not report an error, everything went well?

What's the best way to check that the copying process went right?

Comment: Boto is just a wrapper so probably: https://serverfault.com/questions/999359/does-aws-cli-do-a-data-integrity-check-on-sync-with-s3

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are using python Boto and i also asume the file you uploaded before was uploaded as a single part then you can get the md5 of the file using following python snipet

**Boto Older then version 3**

```
#bandwidth friendly no need to download content
md5_b1 = bucket1.get_key('your file name').etag[1 :-1]
md5_b2 = bucket2.get_key('your file name').etag[1 :-1]
if md5_b1 == md5_b2:
    print('Your file was coppied successfully no corruption')
```

**Boto version 3 (tested)**

for boto3 following utility function can be used its tested on boto3==1.18.18

```
def GetMD5(bucket, key):
        s3_cli = boto3.client('s3')
        response = s3_cli.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        return response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['etag'].strip('"')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
It looks like older boto code, are you sure that it works with boto3?

Comment: i am testing and experimenting

Comment: @Sebastian Check my edited answer